# Extracting pattern in a string in pyspark using regex

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a string named `rasm_4_Becv0_0_1234_rasm_3exm`
I want to extract the digits after `Becv` that is `0_0_1234` in pysaprk.

Can anyone please suggest what will be the regular expression for this pattern?
The digits are changing.

Comment: did the provided answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should be able to extract the pattern that you are looking for.
I added some dummy data in the form of:

```
strings
-------------------------------
rasm_4_Becv0_0_1230_rasm_3exm
rasm_4_Becv0_0_1231_rasm_3exm
rasm_4_Becv0_0_1232_rasm_3exm
rasm_4_Becv0_0_1233_rasm_3exm
rasm_4_Becv0_0_123{i}_rasm_3exm
```

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, StructField
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# build the DataFrame
data = []
for i in range(5):
    data.append(f"rasm_4_Becv0_0_123{i}_rasm_3exm")
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[Row(x) for x in data], schema=StructType([StructField("strings", StringType(), True)]))

# extract the pattern
regex = r"(\d_\d_\d{4})"
group_idx = 1
df_new = df.withColumn("extracted_string", f.regexp_extract(f.col("strings"), regex, group_idx))
```

This pattern works as well as the dollar sign works as a group extractor. So $1 means group1 and $2 means group2 and so on.

```
# extract the pattern
regex = r".*(\d_\d_\d{4}).*"
replacement = "$1"
df_new = df.withColumn("extracted_string", f.regexp_replace(f.col("strings"), regex, repl))
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will include anything between Becv and _rasm

```
Becv(.*)_rasm
```

Use https://regex101.com/ to try out yourself ;)